# How to save user's input in UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I wanted to know how can I save a user's input when the user enters something from his mobile phone in the `UITextField`?

If I just use the text field and run the app I can enter data in the text field but when I close the application the data is gone. So how can I store that data permanently and show it again after the application is closed and reopened. Is there any way to save it?

Comment: Many ways.  Perhaps look at `NSUserDefaults` for the simplest starting point.

Comment: use `NSUserDefault` to store data.

Comment: You can use `NSUserDefaults` or `Core Data` for that

Comment: NSUserDefaults, a file (.txt, or whatever), CoreData, KeyChain if it's sensitive information like passwords, etc.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should save the text when user did editing before user close the application(e.g. saved by NSUserDefaults):

```
self.yourTextView.delegate = self;

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.markedTextRange == nil) 
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:textView.text forKey:@"userText"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

Then, load the text that user saved before when user open your application again:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.yourTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userText"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

We can save data into 3 data base

If you want to store single data into db, you can use

[NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

For store

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:textView.text forKey:@"textviewdata"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

For Retrieve

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *strTextViewText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"textviewdata"]];
```

Then Store a larger amount of data,we can use

[SQLite](https://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

[CoreData](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to save data inside application.

1. create local database using `sqlite` or `coredata` both provides facilty to save data locally and before use please find the different situations to use these databases.
2. using `NSUserDefaluts` but not recomemded because `NSUserDefaults` aren’t meant to store sensitive information for more information [see imp link](https://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/) see example also if you still.

To store data using `NSUserDefaluts`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.textfield.text forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

To get data anywhere inside app:

```
object = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.urtextfield.text forKey:@"savedtext"];
    }
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
      self.urtextfield.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"savedtext"];
    }
```